# Find Max Line Count for Unity UI.Text

Tags: unity, c#, gui, text

I'm trying to determine the max line count of a `UI.Text` with `VerticalOverflow` set to `truncate` so that the line count can be used later. So far I came up this code which obviously is rather unpractical and perhaps even dangerous:

```
/// <summary>
///     Returns the max visible line count of a UI.Text component. The text's vertical
///     overflow must be set to truncate or this method will return 0.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int GetMaxLineCount(Text text)
{
    if (text == null || text.verticalOverflow != VerticalWrapMode.Truncate) return 0;
    var textBackup = text.text;
    var lineCount = 0;
    text.text = "";
    while (true)
    {
        text.text += "\n";
        Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
        var nextLineCount = text.cachedTextGenerator.lineCount;
        if (lineCount == nextLineCount) break;
        lineCount = nextLineCount;
    }
    text.text = textBackup;
    return lineCount;
}
```

Is there any better way to (pre)determine the max line count of a UI.Text component (before text is truncated at the bottom)?